# Using CSS transition to change element position

Tags: html, css

I want to change a position of a div on hover, which I can do with following code. As I hover anywhere on the `.box`, the position of `.info` is changed from bottom to top.

I want to change its position with the transition effect, so that it looks like is moving up instead up appearing quickly. Can it be done using the CSS only?

I am trying to use the transition property but cannot make it work. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SGw04SV.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="title">Hello world</div>
        <div class="more">more stuff</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.info{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    
}

.box:hover .info{
    top: 0;
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/fXXsS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the transition to the `.info`. You can only animate a property, not the layout:

```css
    .box {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .info {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; margin-top: 90%;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;    
    }

    .box:hover .info {
        margin-top: 0%;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Recode/fXXsS/2/

edit: I know, at the moment it's a little hack, because if the height changes, there's a problem. ;)

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xCaie) is a possibile answer

HTML:

```html
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SGw04SV.jpg"/>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="title">Hello world</div>
            <div class="more">more stuff</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
    .box {
      position: relative;
    }
    .box img {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .info {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      margin-top: 400px;
    }
    
    .box:hover .info {
      margin-top: 0;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: Applying the transition-property to the :hover-state, has one problem: only normal -> hover is animated, but not hover -> normal.

Comment: Add transition to the info class(no hover) :
.info {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  margin-top:400px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
}